# Firebase offline capabilities

Tags: firebase, offline

I'm implementing an Android app that collects data throughout the day. When the user returns home where there is internet connection, then the app will push data to backend.

I have been looking into Firebase for this. It has offline capabilities that would save data into disk in case there is temporary network interruptions.

My question is whether the offline feature fits with my scenario? Is the feature designed for short term interruptions, or works with any kind of interruptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with any kind of interruptions. So if you don't have an internet connection during the day, when you come back home in the evening, all the changes made when you were offline will be pushed to Firebase database.

To achieve this you need to use this line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps.